# Keep your filthy designer hands off my property values!

Tags: .net, controls, designer

Is there an attribute I can set on my control's property to prevent the designer-generated code from ever setting a value to it?

Answer (score 3):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibilityattribute.aspx

This looks useful.

Comment: That's the one...that said...be warned. It doesn't always work. WinForms designer is evil.

Answer (score 2):

The [`BrowsableAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx) will remove it from the property grid, if you provide `false` to the constructor:

```
[Browsable(false)]
```

If you set it with a [default value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx), *this value* won't be serialized by the designer:

```
[DefaultValue("MyDefaultValue")]
```